# Как настроить главную цену и цены опций?

Tags: opencart

Как можно реализовать такую фишку? К примеру у меня основная цена и еще опции: 22 дюйма (цена 1), 24 дюйма(цена 2), 28 дюймов(цена 3) и основная (цена).  К примеру я выбираю опцию, у меня считается только опция, если я не выбираю опцию, то считается основная цена.

Answer (score 1):

Если еще актуально: можно установить [модуль дополнительных действий с ценой опций](https://opencartforum.com/files/file/619-vqmod-dopolnitelnye-deistviia-s-tcenoi-optcii/) и назначать нужной опции цену не +/- от цены товара а =. Тогда цена опции будет перезаписывать базовую цену товара.